# cin doesnt take another input correctly after a set of input from while

Tags: c++

This is the **file_processing_tutor.cpp** file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "ClientData.h"

using namespace std;

void outputline(int, const string &, double);
void outputlineDAT(ostream&, const ClientData &);

int main() {
    cout << endl << "Phase 1 Writing Data to txt" << endl;
    cout << "Make Sure Input is already ready before running" << endl;
    ofstream outClientFile("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Streaming DT Data/test.txt", ios::out);
    if(!outClientFile){
        cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    
    
    cout << "Enter the account, name, and balance" << endl << "Enter end-of-file to end input." << endl;
    
    int count_input = 0;
    int account;
    string name;
    double balance;

    while(cin >> account >> name >> balance){
        ++count_input;
        outClientFile << account << ' ' << name << ' ' << balance << endl;
        cout << "? (Input Count = " << count_input << ") " << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl << "Phase 2 Reading Data from txt" << endl;
    ifstream inClientFile("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Streaming DT Data/test.txt", ios::in);

    if(!inClientFile){
        cerr << "File Could not be Opened" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << left << setw(10) << "Account" << setw(13) << "Name" << "Balance" << endl << fixed << showpoint;
    while(inClientFile >> account >> name >> balance){
        outputline(account, name, balance);
    }

    cout << endl << "Phase 3 Writing 100 Blank Records to Random Access File .Dat" << endl;
    fstream outCredit("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Streaming DT Data/credit.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(!outCredit){
        cerr << "File Could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ClientData blankClient;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        outCredit.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&blankClient), sizeof(ClientData));
    }

    cout << endl << "Phase 4 Writing Data Randomly to a Random Access File .Dat" << endl;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    cout << "Enter Account Number (1 to 100, 0 to end input)\n?";

    ClientData client;
    cin >> account;

    cout << "Account Input: " << account << endl;

    while(account > 0 && account <= 100){
        cout << "Enter lastname, firstname, balance \n?";
        cin >> lastName >> firstName >> balance;

        client.setAccountNumber(account);
        client.setLastName(lastName);
        client.setFirstName(firstName);
        client.setBalance(balance);

        outCredit.seekp((client.getAccountNumber() - 1) * sizeof(ClientData));
        cout << "Enter Account Number (1 to 100, 0 to end input)\n?";
        cin >> account;
    }  
    return 0;
}

void outputline(int account, const string &name, double balance){
    cout << left << setw(10) << account << setw(13) << name << setw(7) 
    << setprecision(2) << right << balance << endl;
}
void outputlineDAT(ostream &output, const ClientData &record){
    output << left << setw(10) << record.getAccountNumber() << setw(16) 
    << record.getLastName() << setw(11) << record.getFirstName() << setw(10) 
    << setprecision(2) << right << fixed << showpoint << record.getBalance() << endl;
}
```

Because I am using **Sublime Text 3**, I set my input in a file called **inputf.in**, this is all my raw input:

```
100 Jones 24.98
200 Doe 345.67
300 White 0
400 Stone -42.16
500 Rich 224.62
450 Harmond 412.5
3
Barker Doug 0
29
Brown Nancy -24.54
96
Stone Sam 34.98
88
Smith Dave 258.34
33 
Dunn Stacey 314.33
0
```

And I see my output as follows from **outputf.out**:

```
Phase 1 Writing Data to txt
Make Sure Input is already ready before running
Enter the account, name, and balance
Enter end-of-file to end input.
? (Input Count = 1) 
? (Input Count = 2) 
? (Input Count = 3) 
? (Input Count = 4) 
? (Input Count = 5) 
? (Input Count = 6) 


Phase 2 Reading Data from txt
Account   Name         Balance
100       Jones          24.98
200       Doe           345.67
300       White           0.00
400       Stone         -42.16
500       Rich          224.62
450       Harmond       412.50

Phase 3 Writing 100 Blank Records to Random Access File .Dat

Phase 4 Writing Data Randomly to a Random Access File .Dat
Enter Account Number (1 to 100, 0 to end input)
?Account Input: 450
```

**Problem:**
So every output in above was ok, until it reached phase 4 where I get to input new data for account variable, Instead of get the input **3** (which is set from the input) it reoutputs the last account data (**450**) ignoring the cin input. thus it didn't input anything to a file called **credit.dat**.

Appreciate any pointers to the issues, Thankyou!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code in the question doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: If your issue is in a distinct phase, I would suggest cutting your code down to an appropriate [mre]. You're going to have a hard time convincing people to slog through code that isn't part of your question.

Comment: @sweenish i see, sorry about that, I will cut unnecessary code and get it clearer

Comment: Please also review the tags you applied, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt well what should you suggest me the tags? not sure what to change

Comment: For one, if you aren't having a problem with sublime text specifically, you would remove that tag.

Comment: @sweenish okay done

Comment: No, it's not. You claim that Phase 4 is having issues. So why is `main()` still running phases 1-3,5? You've now excluded definitions that you're using. Did you read the link I posted about what a [mre] is?

Comment: You need to clear the error flag on cin if it's already on an error state ...

Comment: @sweenish well if i were to cut the phase 1-3 and 5, will it make debugging harder? because some variable of the code are shared through the phase, so i kinda doubt it

Comment: Do you not know? Have you not tried using a debugger yourself?

Comment: Jovan, concerning the tags, I just wanted you to read their descriptions. What to do would have been clear automatically.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt When I read the c++ tag description, it tells that i should just tag with c++ version, is that it? if thats it, i am not sure, but when i check my gcc version it shows version 6.3.0

Comment: @sweenish sorry no, because its file processing, i cant check it through online compiler either, meanwhile when i run it in sublime, it didnt give any error

Comment: The code can be used with a debugger; file processing is beside the point. Your last sentence makes no sense. Compiling without error is mostly meaningless. As evidenced by the fact that you're here. Do you have warnings enabled?

Comment: After finally having a harder look at the code, you try to open the same file with multiple streams at the same time. Don't do that. I'm not sure you're ready to be writing a tutorial on this stuff yet.